# GREP out lines with special characters except

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to add an exception to `grep -v [[:punct:]]` not to exclude lines with some predefined special characters. In the following example: `-` and `_`

Input:

```
Color red
Color _ yellow
Color blu+e
Color gr-een
Color bla!ck
```

Expected output:

```
Color red 
Color _ yellow
Color gr-een
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/[-_]/ || !/[[:punct:]]/' file
Color red
Color _ yellow
Color gr-een
```

This gets lines that either of these:

- have `-` or `_`.
- do not contain `[[:punct:]]`.

---

To solve problem with line like `Color _ yellow !`, you can do:

```
awk '/[-_]/ {a=$0;gsub(/[-_]/,"",a);if (a!~/[[:punct:]]/) print} !/[[:punct:]]/' file
```

Comment: I also thought this, but would also print lines like `Color _ yellow !`, which I don't think is the intended behaviour.

Comment: @fedorqui Some golfing would be done trough the testing to solve this pussle if that is OPs requirement.

Comment: @fedorqui Added solution to remove lines like `Color _ yellow !` from the output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of figuring out what you want to exclude, state what you want to keep:

```
grep '^[[:alnum:][:blank:]_-]*$'
```